# engineered or solid wood flooring over plywood subfloor

Tags: flooring

I wonder if anyone can help! I live in a first floor flat in an old listed building and have recently had 18mm ply laid over my whole floor, over the old floorboards, this was needed in order to level the floor in order to lay a new wood floor over the top. (the floor was soooo uneven!!) my question now is, the flat is open plan, that is, the kitchen/dining/living is all open and at the same level. I have read somewhere that engineered wood is better than solid for use in kitchens, because of possible water escape. The kitchen will only have the sink (the washing machine going elsewhere.) I have looked at engineered wood and see that it is basically a 3/4mm 'wear layer' ie solid wood and then plywood or hdf core. Now, because I already have an 18mm layer of plywood, could I use one of the 11mm solid woods over this or would I still have a problem in case of water escape? what do you experts think? If you do recommend engineered flooring, is the type with the HDF core ok for kitchen areas?  any advice or recommendations would be gratefully received!! many thanks in advance, Julie

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; let's see if one of our pros can give an answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Solid wood was used for centuries for flooring _long_ before engineered flooring was developed. A good finish should protect it from the occasional spill, but it will require mantainance and refinishing on occasion. If you're expecting to have regular "swimming pool" sized incidents, you may be better off with engineered flooring. The choice is yours.

Comment: I will never look back at solid wood flooring unless you're looking for something very exotic. I find engineered flooring better in every way. You can even find engineered flooring (such as Owens plankfloor) which has the same wear layer as solids.

Comment: Many factors favor engineered flooring, more choices for design and color, better match in consistency in color and apprearance.  All engineer flooring can handle the occasional spill and quick wipeup. For a kitchen, where a leak may not be notice right away, water resistance is highly recommended.    The kitchen area normally requires more frequent heavy cleaning, mopping spills, dropping,etc.